# Inserting data in database using foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to insert data received from POST method.When Im inserting it , each recoed is inserted 3 times 
this is my code

```
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $sid=$_POST['sid'];
    //$user=$_POST['user'];
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $host= "localhost";
    $dbname="offlinesurvey";


    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $date = date('YmdHis');
    $name=$sid.'_'.$date;
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
    $sql_create="CREATE TABLE  `offlinesurvey`.`lime_survey_$sid` ( `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,whenadded DATETIME, `code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`answer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , UNIQUE `id` (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_create)){

    }
    else {
      "No..No";
    }
       foreach((array)  $_POST as $k => $v) {
      echo $v;

          $sql = "insert into lime_survey_$sid(user,whenadded,code,answer) values('".$_POST['user'][$k]."',Now(),'".$_POST['code'][$k]."', '".$v."')";

                     mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    }






    ?>
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Why are you using for each loop is the posted data contain array of  values?

Comment: can You give an example to do that ?

Comment: For each of the fields you are getting in $_POST, your foreach loop is going to execute, hence resulting into 3 times data as you have 3 input fields.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The probleme is that each record is inserted 3 times ,

Comment: Lets see an example of a typical `$_POST` data set

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `foreach` loop in this situation. You will always have the same number of users (1) to insert data for in this script. You would use `foreach` when there are multiple and/or unknown sets of data which are stored in an array. `$_POST` is an array, but you can access the form input like you did on the first three lines:

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST['answer']; // Set Post array from form to variables
$code = $_POST['code']; // Use could filter/validate here
$sid = $_POST['sid']; // I usually begin these variables with "dirty", "external", etc. so I remember not to trust it.
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

Please note that you must never trust user input. You must treat it as potentially malicious. More on that in a second.

Now that your form uploads stored in PHP variables, you don't need to reference Post again.

Good for using MySQLI. However, the code you are using is still vulnerable to injection and malicious (or even innocent) code (use query only when the query is hard coded and will not be executed more than once). You need to use prepared statements and [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead. Also, I wouldn't give the database user CREATE TABLE privileges. Instead, it's best to just make a column with the "sid." This will also save you from 1082384917 tables once the bots find your site. This will go in a table "lime_survey" that you should create in your database with the appropriate fields.

```
// Don't forget connection settings. DON'T use root in production.
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$whenadded = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

$insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `lime_survey` (`sid`, `user`, `whenadded`, `code`, `answer`) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, 'sssss', $sid, $user, $whenadded, $code, $answer);
mysqli_stmt_execute($insert);
mysqli_stmt_close($insert);
mysqli_close($con);
```

This approach will create just one row per instance of this script. Additionally, it is more secure; however, be sure to properly escape the data if you retrieve it from the table (this depends on the application in which the data will be used).

In the future, utilize `echo` and print all variables and arrays so you can better understand what is happening.

---

### Edit with full code:

I created an example for you with error notices, better protection against database injection (i.e. using prepared statement with `bind_param`), and escaping external data when printed back to html.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$answer = $_POST['answer']; // Set Post array from form to variables
$code = $_POST['code']; // Use could filter/validate here
$sid = $_POST['sid']; // I usually begin these variables with "dirty", "external", etc. so I remember not to trust it.

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$whenadded = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $host= "localhost";
    $dbname="offlinesurvey";    

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `lime_survery` (`sid`, `whenadded`, `code`, `answer`) values (?,?,?,?)");
echo mysqli_error($con);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, 'ssss', $sid, $whenadded, $code, $answer);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($insert)){
    // Be sure to escape external content!!!
        echo '<p>The following values were received successfully:<br><br>SID: '.htmlspecialchars($sid).'<br>Code: '
        .htmlspecialchars($code).'<br>User: '.htmlspecialchars($answer).'<br>Added: '.$whenadded.
        '</p><p>You may submit a new survey response below.</p>';
}else{
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_stmt_close($insert);
mysqli_close($con); 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>Lime Survey</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Lime Survery</h1>
<form method="POST">
<p>SID: <input type="text" name="sid" autofocus></p>
<p>Code: <input type="text" name="code"></p>
<p>Answer: <input type="text" name="answer"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2**

Here's the create table SQL for the test table inside the databse offlinesurvery that I used:

```
CREATE TABLE `lime_survery` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `whenadded` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `answer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What's the error? Usually, the error actually relates to the previous line of code and it fails because of an unexpected (i.e. false) state of the prepare. This is usually due to bad syntax or a problem within the database structure. I'll update the answer shortly with better error handling and also test it.

Comment: Updated answer with a full code example. Notice how I added in `echo` and the appropriate mysqli error functions to provide feedback when something goes unexpected (or to let you know when everything worked). This is the most important concept to share with you, as it will help you learn to debug your code on your own. Also, the PHP manual is pretty detailed and has good code examples.